# What request status should I apply on wrong client applies?

Tags: node.js, http

I'm trying to apply request status to my file.
For now, I have 3 ifs. Can you tell me what status to add to each one of them and why?
for example: first one res.status(400).render....

```js
exports.register = (req, res) => {
  // Get the POST data
  const { firstName, lastName, email, password, passwordConfirm } = req.body;

  // Check if everything is filled.
  if (firstName === '' || lastName === '' || email === '' || password === '' || passwordConfirm === ''  ) {
    return res.render('register', {
      message: 'One of the fields is missing. Please try again.'
    });
  } else {
    db.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = ?', [email], (error, results) => {
      // Check if email already exists
      if (results.length > 0) {
        return res.render('register', {
          message: 'The email address is already exists. Please try a different one.'
        });
        // Check if passwords match
      } else if (password !== passwordConfirm) {
          return res.render('register', {
            message: 'Passwords do not match. Please try again.'
          });
        }
    });
  }


};
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

When a field is missing, the client clearly made a bad request, so [status 400 (Bad Request)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400) would be appropriate there. (Though, ideally, this validation would be done on the client-side too, and prevent users who haven't tampered with the client code from making such a request to the server in the first place)

If the submitted email address conflicts, [401 Unauthorized](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401) is an option - it indicates that if the user re-submits with non-conflicting credentials, the request will go through successfully, and that there was nothing inherently wrong with the request other than the fact that it didn't pass a requirement that only the server could determine.

Status 400 is also appropriate if the passwords don't match - and like when a field is missing, that is validation that should also be done on the client-side, so that such requests don't make it to the server in the first place under normal circumstances (and if a request *does* make it to the server, it's a badly formatted request, hence 400).

But, keep in mind that status codes only *really* matter for how your client-side code deals with them. As long as you know what sorts of statuses and messages your server can reply with, and write your client accordingly, you can still make a working app, without having to care a lot about the precisely applicable semantics of HTTP status codes.